# Insert selected records to another table in VB.Net and access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vb6

My name is Sarfaraz. I am developing a project in VB.Net and MSAccess 2007. I have a listbox control that is being populated from a table in Access called items. I am using a combination of two listbox's to select differnt values. I want to get the rate of the individual item when I hit the save button. The values are stored in a clients table. I am storing the data like Sugar=5 Biscuits=10  etc.

I am using a VB6 textbox and Recordset and need to know how I would implement the same thing in VB.Net

Comment: I really like Access (Jet/ACE), but it is not the place for medical records.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured the answer but it is taking a very long time to perform the task and my system is going in a busy mode for almost 10 seconds. Is there anything wrong in this code Please have a look
Thank you. 
Here is my code

```
Con.Open()
For l_index = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1

query = ("select Investigation.rate " & _
"from Investigation WHERE (((Investigation.Investigation) = '" & ListBox2.Items(l_index) & "'));")

Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand(query, Con)
'Con.Open()

Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader

reader.Read()
'Console.WriteLine(reader(0))
txtrate.Text = reader.GetString(0)


reader.Close()
'Con.Close()

' Con.Close()

'End If

Dim SqlString As String = "Insert Into patients (Receipt_No, OPD_MRD,Patientname,Investigation,Receipt_date,Receipt_time,rate) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SqlString, Con)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Receipt_No", txtreceiptno.Text.Trim())
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("OPD_MRD", txtopd.Text.Trim())
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Patientname", txtname.Text.Trim())
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Investigation", CStr(ListBox2.Items(l_index)).ToString())
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Receipt_date", lbldate.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Receipt_time", lbltime.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("rate", txtrate.Text.Trim())
'Con.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Next
Con.Close()
```